# C++ template class that creates instances of other classes

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to C++ and I don't know about template class but I think I can use template for my problem. I have two classes,

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    Foo (int a, char b);
};

class Bar
{
 public:
    Bar (int a);
};
```

And these classes are not related to each other.

My question is, is it possible to create a template class to create instances of `Foo` and `Bar`? Something that could be used like this:

```
TemplateClass<Foo>::createClass();
```

But I'm not sure about the parameter.

Comment: What would the return *type* of this mythical function be? How would you use it?

Comment: In addition to what Kerrek said: *why* would you want to have such a function? If the classes are unrelated, why have a common function to create instances? Which parameters do you want to pass to the constructors?

Comment: This is almost surely an XY problem. Can you please describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: the createClass method is a static method of the TemplateClass which will return the class like Foo or Bar. Actually I'm not sure what I'm doing, I just thought about it.

Comment: Having the ability to lift object construction into a functor can be quite useful. That's why things like [Boost.Factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html) exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use C++11 for this.

```
template<typename T>
class TemplateClass
{
public:
   template<class... Args>
   static T createClass(Args&&... args)
   {
      return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
};

Foo f = TemplateClass<Foo>::createClass(1, '1');
Bar b = TemplateClass<Bar>::createClass(1);
```

Or with C++03 use different overloads.

```
template<typename T>
class TemplateClass
{
public:
   static T createClass()
   {
      return T();
   }
   template<typename Arg1>
   static T createClass(const Arg1& arg)
   {
      return T(arg);
   }
   template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
   static T createClass(const Arg1& arg1, const Arg2& arg2)
   {
      return T(arg1, arg2);
   }
};
```

And so on...

Comment: What is different overloads? Thanks.

Comment: Nice. Great. I think this is the solution. Waiting 1 minute to accept. =) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not normal functions and thus cannot be used with `bind` or other functional mechanisms easily. Writing a wrapper with limited functionality is easy with C++11 as ForEver shows, but this can become tricky without C++11 and when you need more than basic functionality. You can use [Boost.Factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html) for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use Boost library in my code. Thanks a lot! I will consider it in the future change of the  design.